# Close windows after X seconds with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to figure out how to solve this problem, then thing is that I need to close a window after 7 seconds everytime this is open, I can manage that the windows close but the time is still counting using SetInterval, then when I open again the windows probably will close because it passed some seconds so the time when the windows close is not exact.

Here the code I m using , and this is the web - https://sergioboado.me/photography

```
setInterval(function() {
  if ($(".sqs-lightbox-close")[0]){
  $(".sqs-lightbox-close")[0].click(function(){
    window.close()
  })
   window.clearTimeout(); 
}
}, 4000);
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You're using setInterval but you're clearing timeout rather than interval. You probably want to use setTimeout?

Comment: hi, yes  also i tried with SetTimeOut, but the function keeps open and the window is closing every seconds and not when the window is open.

Comment: i also try this functionbut is not working as I need it

Comment: `function closewindow(){
  if ($(".sqs-lightbox-close")[0]){
 $(".sqs-lightbox-close")[0].click(function(){
    window.close()
    setTimeout(closewindow, 5000);
   $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});

}
 console.log("yeah")
}}

setTimeout(closewindow,7000);

`

Answer (score 0):

```
   var myTimer = setInterval(function() {
                  if ($(".sqs-lightbox-close")[0]){
                      $(".sqs-lightbox-close")[0].click(function(){
                      window.close()
                   })
                  clearInterval(myTimer); 
                }
               }, 4000);

try this...
```

Comment: Hello Santhosh, thanks for your help, I have tried the code you wrote but still is not working at all the main problem is that the window just close at the very first time and then if i open another window with this class then the windows does not close again, so it closes just the first time,  and if i use SetInverval, the window closes everytime after the seconds set but not everytime the window is open.